# Validating and matching a specifically formatted string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre, preg-match-all

I have the following regex pattern which works fine:

```
#^(.+?)=(.+?)$#D
```

However I want to extend it so it supports the following example inputs:

> some text=some more text;something
>
> some text=some more text;something;something
>
> some text=some more text;something;something;something

As you can see from the above example inputs the semi-colon (`;`) character is being used as a seperator and is used to seperate text (it is between text).

I guess I can use the following regex pattern below - it will only work when theres is one, but won't if there is more text seperated by a semi-colon... I know I can probably add something like `[;]*` but I want the validation to be strict to ensure it is in that format (so there can't semi-colons just anywhere they have to be between text only).

```
#^(.+?)=(.+?);(.+?)$#D
```

If it helps I'm currently using PHP's `preg_match()` function (so the matches can be utilized in `array()` form).

I'm not limited to using regex as that was the only method I could think of, therefore I'm welcome to other methods or any method which can be used alongside this (providing the results can be easily attained as an array LOL).

Also I'd like to note whilst writing this (and flicking through the tagging system) I had a news flash...perhaps using `preg_match_all()` with the `PCRE` recursive functionality could be a possible solution?

Appreciate all responses and thank you for all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `explode()` on the second half to explode on any semicolons?

Comment: Hmm did'nt think of that, but would that ensure correct form?

Comment: Thanks I used explode() with a combination of array_map('trim', $arr) and array_filter() to weed out invalid entries.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
#^(.+?)=((.+?)(;)?)+$#D
```

Comment: Unfourtanetly does not work properly, the produced matches are not whats expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`#^(.+?)=(.+?)(;(.+?))+?$#D`

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
#^(.+?)=(.+?)(?:;(.+?))+?$#D
```